# jsonArray = (JSONArray)objIn.readObject(); raise java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor

Tags: java, android

I get an error while receiving a JSONArray from an ObjectOutputStream

```
ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());
```

I'm trying to retrieve my Stream like this:

```
jsonArray = (JSONArray)objIn.readObject();
```

and it raise the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.beans.PropertyDescriptor
at libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55)
at java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:479)
at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getDexCacheType(ArtMethod.java:198)
at java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod.getParameterTypes(ArtMethod.java:143)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:174)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:808)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.computeSerialVersionUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:566)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.createClassDesc(ObjectStreamClass.java:279)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookupStreamClass(ObjectStreamClass.java:1087)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2337)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1643)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
```

I tried to add the openbeans.jar in my Eclipse libs folder (even if I do not use it) but same error...
any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats not, how you add jars as libaries to your project.

You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the 
*Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path*.

Under Libraries tab, click **Add External JARs** and give the Jar.

Comment: in latest Eclipse version by adding Jars in the Libs folder adds them automatically in Private libraries path

Comment: Is that so? Ok, didnt knew since I'm using IntelliJ for a long time now.

Comment: I tried to add it in the build path manually but I have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I changed the server part and tried to send/read an other type of Object (String and JSonObject) and both are working....
So it seems that it comes from JSONByteArray but I would need to dig a bit more on it....